# RAW Format videos database

Tags: video, video-quality, codec, raw

there is an online database for raw videos?
I wanted to download some videos in RAW Format for a university work and I can't find none. 
The job I have to do is to encode the RAW video with different codecs, but for that I will need some RAW videos. All the videos I found are encoded with some codec. Can you help me?